# Swift - getting generic type's class

Tags: generics, swift

I have very basic models like

```
class Model {

}

class User : Model {

} 

class Group : Model {

}
```

Now I need to check for the generics type to know which class is sent as a parameter

```
func getRepository<ModelType: Model>() {
   if (typeof(ModelType) == User.self) {
       // Do something specific to User
   } else {
       .....
   }
}
```

But I could not figure out how to GET THE CLASS of a GENERIC TYPE.

Much appreciate for your answers.

Cheers

Comment: How are you planning to call the function?

Comment: Unless you're passing a parameter to `getRepository` the compiler has no way of inferring the type of `ModelType` (other than it's some sort of `Model`). If you try to call `getRepository()` with it defined like this (even with nothing in it) you'll get a compile error. I'm guessing you actually want something like: `func getRepository<ModelType: Model>(model: ModelType)` ?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I intent to call it as `getRepository<User>()`

Comment: @MikeS `getRepository<ModelType: Model>(model: ModelType)` looks ugly, don't you think? I should be able to get the Generic Type somehow just like C#

Answer (score 0):

How about this https://gist.github.com/MartinJNash/e2bb27937711f350aa44? I'm not sure if it works, but the idea is get the class name in string then compare them:

```
class Model {
    class func classString() -> String {
        return NSStringFromClass(self)
    }
}


func getRepository<ModelType: Model>() {
   if (ModelType.classString() == User.classString()) {
       // ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @blue-smith! That looks like a solution for me now.